# side-by-side subfigure in Sharelatex

Tags: latex

I am interested to make a figure with multiple subfigures. By some search I found different ways but not working for me. May be I am using shareLatex and others use proper Latex (I don't know very much difference so sorry if I say something odd). Given below is the code...

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.2in]{Bilder/sample.png}
        \caption{Sample1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.2in]{Bilder/sample.png}
        \caption{sample2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption place holder}
\end{figure}
```

My Output is something like this.

[image]

This is neither desired nor same as by the suggested Solutions. 
Sample of suggested solution is as below. How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 23):

I found this code and it is working perfectly for subfigures. For two subfigures use

```
\begin{figure}%
\centering
\subfigure[Sample1]{%
\label{fig:first}%
\includegraphics[height=2in]{Bilder/sample.png}}%
\qquad
\subfigure[Sample2]{%
\label{fig:second}%
\includegraphics[height=2in]{Bilder/sample.png}}%
\caption{sample}
\end{figure}
```

with sample output

[image]

And for cascading subfigures....

```
\begin{figure}%
\centering
\subfigure[][]{%
\label{fig:ex3-a}%
\includegraphics[height=2in]{Bilder/sample.png}}%
\hspace{8pt}%
\subfigure[][]{%
\label{fig:ex3-b}%
\includegraphics[height=2in]{Bilder/sample.png}} \\
\subfigure[][]{%
\label{fig:ex3-c}%
\includegraphics[height=2in]{Bilder/sample.png}}%
\hspace{8pt}%
\subfigure[][]{%
\label{fig:ex3-d}%
\includegraphics[height=2in]{Bilder/sample.png}}%
\caption[A set of four subfigures.]{A set of four subfigures:
\subref{fig:ex3-a} describes the first subfigure;
\subref{fig:ex3-b} describes the second subfigure;
\subref{fig:ex3-c} describes the third subfigure; and,
\subref{fig:ex3-d} describes the last subfigure.}%
\label{fig:ex3}%
\end{figure}
```

sample for 4 subfigure

[image]

Comment: should remember to import subfigure at the top of the file.

\usepackage{subfigure}

Comment: What are the percent signs for? Don't they just start comments?

Comment: After the `%` character there is a newline character too. The newline characters are not ignored by LaTeX (they work like blank characters). A trick to avoid all the side effects that may cause is to "hide" that newline character into a comment, so that LaTeX really ignores it. With this trick, LaTeX sees the line with the comment and the next one as a single line with no blanks in between. Another essential part of the trick is that there must be no blank character before the comment (i.e. between `}` and `%`), lest that character will introduce the same side effects as the newline character.

Comment: This code is obsolete. It's recommended to use the newer subfig or subcaption packages: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439970/no-counter-subfiguresave-defined-this-error-appear-when-subfloat-command